# If I play Left 4 Dead 2 through Steam, will I still get Live achievements for it?

Tags: steam, achievements, xbox-network, left-4-dead-2

Since Steam has it's own achievements for the game, do they replace the Live ones or can I earn both?

Comment: Although the question proposes L4D2 in the title, I didn't add the tag because both the question and the answers seem to apply to any game available to both systems. Unless someone can provide better input, that is.

Comment: In this case it's specific to Steam/XBL I think, there's another question about XBL/Games for Windows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You get Xbox Live achievements if you play the 360 version, Steam achievements if you play the PC version

Answer (score 5):

Steam achievements are completely separate from XBox Live achievements.